# Is this edit too minor?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have suggested an edit today which was rejected as too minor. But does it look like too minor? I have improved the title and removed redundancy. The edit can be found at [this link](https://movies.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1418).

Comment: I would like to note that **titles are particularly important** to this site, so any substantive, good-faith improvements — even if they might otherwise be perceived as "minor" — should be submitted.

Comment: But the edit is not improving anything good. Even removing the link and adding grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this specific edit doesn't strike me as too minor, my biggest problem with it is getting rid of the link to the movie in question.

While not required by any means, it is always *nice* to have a link to the movie you're asking about.

If it were me reviewing the edit, I would have hit a separate button named "Improve this edit", which takes your edit and allow me to further alter it, which I would have put the link back in and touched up the grammar a tad. (which I will probably end up doing now)

Considering this edit was approved by the asker, and rejected by another user, I'd say it's just a point of disagreement, which is fine.

---

An edit I would consider to be too minor is if you were to edit the same post and try to just capitalize a word, or add a punctuation mark.  Because any edit to a post bumps it up to the top of the front page, these restrictions are in place in order to prevent post "bumping"; a popular method in forums to garner attention to a post that is much older.

Comment: @Mistu4u. Yes, I would not say it was too minor either - but why remove a valid link?

Comment: Okay, I got it. Deleted the link unintentionally. Sorry guys!

Comment: I have rejected it because its just removing a link which is added by me, I love the question which have links which helps future visitors. So that's the reason for my rejection. And other rejection reason is `had not` which is a grammar mistake in the edit and its not helping in any improvement to the question. Anyways i didn't have any personal issue at all.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, no not a personal issue at all. Removing the link was a mistake by me. But you could have edited it like tyler said because the edit was not too minor!anyways dont feel offended!